# .htaccess file redirect pages that start with the same string

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect two pages and i am using thw following code

```
RewriteRule projects/(.+) /Pages/Shop/SinglePortfolio.php?ID=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule projects$ /Pages/Shop/Portfolio.php [NC,L]
```

The first page will be like /projects/project-no-one
The second will be the /projects

This rule is currenty shows the Portfolio.php page, but not the SinglePortfolio.php (404)
If i revert the rules  shows the SinglePortfolio.php page, but not the SinglePortfolio.php (404)

Tried

- Without the $ at projects$
- Other regular expressions
- changing the projects/(.+) to project/(.+) but the prefix is the same and that seems to cause a problem.

Comment: What is the result when you update the regex to this `^projects/(.+)/?$` and `^projects/?$`?

Comment: s shows the Portfolio.php page, but not the SinglePortfolio.php

Comment: 404 is page not found error.  Does the SinglePortfolio.php file exist in the given file path?

Comment: Do you also have a physical directory called `/projects`? Or perhaps a `projects.php` file? You should certainly be _anchoring_ the regex, since the regex are currently ambiguous, matching the URL anywhere in the URL-path. What other directives do you have?

Comment: Yes, when I revert the commands it is shown properly

Comment: "If i revert the rules shows the SinglePortfolio.php page, but not the SinglePortfolio.php (404)" - presumably you mean "...but not the Portfolio.php (404)"?

Comment: Presumably the `.htaccess` file is in the document root and `/projects/project-no-one` is a root-relative URL?

Comment: RewriteRule ^projects/(.+)/?$ /Pages/Shop/SinglePortfolio.php?ID=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^projects/?$ /Pages/Shop/Portfolio.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule about /Pages/Content/AboutUs.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/404.php [L]
ErrorDocument 500 /error_redirect.php
RewriteRule  /index.php [L]

htaccess is like that and is at the root of the site folder

the files that its trying to access are both under the folders /pages/shop
and they are properly shown under some cases i described below (not 404) but the two redirects dont seem to work together

Comment: Please edit your question to include code blocks and additional information. (Attempting to post unformatted regex can omit certain characters, apart from it being unreadable to begin with.)

Comment: Solved it, seems like it was an error higher at the htaccess affecting the first line of rewrite rules. Thank you all